# Jquery gif snow with 2 animated gifs

Tags: jquery, animation, gif

Hi I have a snow gif animation with 2 different gifs here:

http://archibaldbutler.com/projects/stack/

One is snowing but not the other, I want them **both** to "snow" down the page instead of just one, at present.

The tutorial I followed was only for having one animated gif. So I duplicated the snowfall script and named it snowfall2.jquery.js

```
    <script src='snowfall.jquery.js'></script>
<script src='snowfall2.jquery.js'></script>
```

I did a search and replace inside snowfall2 for replacing "snowfall" with "snowfall2".

In the header of my index.html, I have added the call to snowfall2.jquery.js which calls the gif image:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>     
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('.collectonme').hide();
        //Start the snow default options you can also make it snow in certain elements, etc.
        $(document).snowfall({image :"images/santa-sneaking-smiley-emoticon2.gif", minSize: 40, maxSize:100});
  $(document).snowfall2({image :"images/santa-sneaking-smiley-emoticon22.gif", minSize: 40, maxSize:100});



    });
     </script>
```

My question is: One gif: the sneaking santa is "snowing" down, but the jumping Santa isn't "snowing". Why?

Comment: one `$(document).ready()` is enough! merge the scripts inside just one document ready

Comment: I have done that now, but my Jumping Santa is still not snowing!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Archie, the answer from Smeegs will tell you why it's not snowing both images.  I messed around with the plugin and set it up (quick hack) to accept an array of images.  Only the first two images will be used, but that should work in your case.

First, replace lines 136, 137 and 138 in the original script with the lines below:

```
if (options.images) {
    flakeMarkup = $(document.createElement("img"));
    flakeMarkup[0].src = this.id % 2 == 0 ? options.images[0] : options.images[1];
```

Then, remove the second script block and second call to the script in your page and update your document.ready() to create an array to pass and fill it with the two images (using your image names of course):

```
var flakeImages = [];
flakeImages[0] = "snowflake.png";
flakeImages[1] = "gemstone.png";
```

Finally, change your call to snowfall to this:

```
$(document).snowfall({ images: flakeImages , minSize: 40, maxSize: 100 });
```

Let me know how it goes.

Comment: Mike, you are a spartan warrior of Javascript, I really want to improve my skills but I find it really hard! Thank you so much for your time, my client is one of the best fashion designers in the world and you have saved the day for me! I will try and work out what you have done, and I have updated the demo. Thanks again!

Comment: Thanks for the praise, although I'm sure my co-workers are glad I don't dress like the Spartans did, regardless of the coding skills.  :) Glad it worked out!

Comment: nice! I was just talking to Archie via twitter about adding this as an actual option to the plugin.

Comment: Cool!  My first psuedo-contribution to an open source project. :)

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming that `snowfall.jquery.js` and `snowfall2.jquery.js` are copies of the same file.

If that's the case, you still just loading the same file twice. It doesn't matter if they have different names.

The function/variable names are the same in both the files so only one of the function will ever get executed, not both.  Which is why just one image is "snowing".  As far as fixing it goes.  I can't help you as I don't know the contents of the jquery plugin.

If the file is small enough, you can go through it and rename all the global variable and functions so that there are two instances of each one.

Comment: Hi, the script is 280 lines. I don't know which variables and functions to rename. I have tried, but I can't get it to work. http://archibaldbutler.com/projects/stack/snowfall2.jquery.js

Comment: Looks like somebody else took the initiative.  Check the other answer

Comment: Thanks for your time Smeegs, issue resolved by Mike Devenney.